# Including PHP file in Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

I have a logger class that I need to log my application processing. How can I include this file in Joomla, when my file is located in the includes folder. I don't want to always have to include the file using ../../../, because then I have to manually count paths everytime I include my class. Is there any way to generate the line that will include that file relatively?

Comment: I find this "close" as very unconstructive. There are constructive responses below though. It seems like some people get high on abusing their karma point privileges.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the Joomla constants for JPath from here: http://docs.joomla.org/JPath like so:

```
include_once (JPATH_ROOT.DS.'includes'.DS.'some.class.php');
```

You can replace JPATH_ROOT with any of the following:

```
JPATH_SITE 
JPATH_BASE
```

Comment: Please note that DS is deprecated in 2.5 and removed in 3.0.

Comment: You are right @Valentin Despa in Joomla 3 it is `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`

Comment: You don't even need it. Just use `/`

Answer (score 2):

use this every where

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lib/sample.lib.php";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

In joomlla 2.5 + never use include_once or require_once to include a class file. PHP has to check if the file has already been loaded before loading the file.

Since joomla 2.5 there is the JLoader::register() method which doesn't use any memory unless you need to execute a method within the class.

http://developer.joomla.org/manual/ch01s04.html